# Does anyone recognize these characters?

Tags: archaic-language, written-language

Does anyone recognize these? I have a hard time recognizing more calligraphy-esque characters. [image]Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The first letter is made of 竹 and 王. This character does not exist.

䇠 is the closest character in Chinese meaning wrench to adjust strings. Unicode U+41E0
笙 is the closest character in Japanese. It means an archaic instrument flutes. Unicode U+7B19

The second letter is made of 日 and 又. This character does not exist, either.
Unfortunately, this one does not have alter characters, I found 䀑 and 叹, I don't think they are related.

I guess this is a name of person or a graffiti, it is so clearly written and the same time the characters do not exist, this does not make a sense to me. Or they were valid in the ancient era...